# Side by side plots in pycaret

Tags: python, plot, pycaret

I am doing regression analysis in pycaret, and plotted residuals and errors.

```py
# create a model
bgr = create_model('gbr')

# residuals plot
plot_model(gbr, plot = 'residuals')

# errors plot
plot_model(gbr, plot = 'error')
```

is there a way I can plot this two graphs side by side?

Comment: Please provide a [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try `plt.subplots()`. See here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html